# What does this statement means on a C program? " While (scanf ("%d", &t) ==1)" And why should I write the rest of the program in that while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

Why should I write the statement "while(scanf("%d",&t)==1)" on the online judges  ? Why I get WRONG verdict if i Submit without this statement ? As my IDE (Code blocks compiler) doesn't find any error .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int t,i;
    float h,l,w;
    while(scanf("%d",&t)==1)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%f%f%f",&l,&w,&h);
            if (l<=20  && w<=20 && h<=20)
                printf("Case %d: good\n",i);
            else
                printf("Case %d: bad\n",i);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: because maybe it is required by the task. `return 0;` does compile fine as well but it does not do the job.

Comment: If you don't use `scanf` you don't get any input value. If you don't use a loop, you don't get multiple executions. It's that simple. What you should use depends on your task. How should we know what you are supposed to do?

Comment: Due to the inner-loop `return 0;` ,  that `while` is pointless. If anything it should be an `if`. And regardless, the result where no parsable initial value is present (i.e. no `return` statement provided in the case of the `while` body is skipped) is wrong. A C program should ensure *all* paths out of `main` specify a proper `return` value (though this is still valid for C++, which has a default `main` return of `0` if the function exists without specifying a `return` value). I suspect that `return 0;` shouldn't be in the loop; it should be *after*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"While" loop isn't necessary. Your code works perfectly fine without while loop, if you write like this:

```
scanf("%d", &t);
for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
```

If you want multiple "t" inputs you should move your return statement after while brace:

```
int t, i;
float h, l, w;
while (scanf("%d", &t)) {

    for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f%f%f", &l, &w, &h);
        if (l <= 20 && w <= 20 && h <= 20)
            printf("Case %d: good\n", i);
        else
            printf("Case %d: bad\n", i);
    }
}
return 0;
```

Also, checking if scanf returned 1 is some kind of protection. scanf returns number of elements filled (int this case 1). If you try to write non-digits it returns 0. You can check what your scanf returns with this or similar code:

```
printf("%d", scanf("%d", &t));
```

Good luck!

Comment: 1)   Why I get wrong verdict from the online judges if i submit code without that statement ? As my IDE (Code blocks) doesn’t find any Error on the code execution .

2)  Can I use this statement " while(scanf"%d",&t)!=EOF;" instead of the previous one ?

Comment: @AhmedTanvir: Perhaps you just enter one test case when you compile in your IDE? These online judges explain exactly what the input looks like and which guarantees it has. They usually even provide example input including the number oftest cases, so that you can test your program. Unless we know what the input from stdin in your IDE looks like, there's no point in insisting that "it works".

Comment: @AhmedTanvir: `scanf` returns the number of conversions or the special constant `EOF` when the input has run out. `scanf("%d", &t)` has three possible outcomes: 1 if the number was converted; 0 if the input couldn't be converted to a number and `EOF` if the end of input has been reached. The variant in the question, which checks against 1, ist the best here, because there's nothing you can do if the input is malformed. The variant in this answer will enter the while loop, even if the end of the input has been reached, because `EOF` is a negative constant.